# Получить данные из html элемента в bash

Tags: html, bash

Я знаю, что в PowerShell можно ввести `$ie.document.getElementById("name").value`, перед этим создав COM-объект Internet Explorer.

А как в Bash получить какое-нибудь значение из HTML и, к примеру, записать его в файл или изменить? И можно ли через Bash закинуть какой-нибудь user script в браузер?

Comment: `tag=body;
 grep $tag file.html |  sed '/<$tag>/,/<\/$tag>/p'` выводит значение между тэгов

Comment: на языке оболочки такое делать весьма громоздко и трудно. лучше воспользоваться средствами операционной системы — предложенными выше grep+sed+... // а ещё лучше — воспользоваться какими-нибудь специализированными программами. типа xml2

Comment: `bash` как и любой другой подобный язык программирования для этого не подходит от слова "совсем"!

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, та первый же тест сломается на этом: `<tag><tag2 attr1="</tag>">чушь</tag2></tag>`. ЯП `bash` **неправильный** интсрумент для этого типа задач. Python + lxml.

Comment: @0andriy нет тэга, которая начинается с `tag2`

Answer (score 0):

Для этой цели лучше использовать язык запросов [XPath](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) и утилиту [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html).

Пример:

```
xmllint --html --xpath 'normalize-space(string(//p))' dummy.html
```

Для стандартной рыбы это нам напечатает её текст.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="la">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simplex exemplum</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
    veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
    velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
    est laborum.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

К сожалению, у этого метода куча ограничений.

- Кодировка должны быть указана в документе явно
- HTML5 теги не поддерживаются

Но не смотря на это, идея использовать внешние инструменты для разбора HTML выглядит многообещающей.